# If for select statement with freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I'd like to know, how i can check the selected value of select tag with freemarker.
I got this code

```
<select name="roles" id="roles">
        <option value="student">Student</option>
        <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
    </select>
```

And I'd like to check if the value is student, I wanna add some inputs, if teacher - somting else.

`<#if roles == 'student'>`
that is the correcnt variant?

Comment: Freemarker is a serverside template engine, which returns HTML in your case. If you  want to add some dynamic content on the page, you need javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use freemarker to use validations that are dynamic. This should be handled by javascript.